# 13.10 update: external backup problem

Tags: 13.10

My actual Ubuntu is 13.10, and I need to update it. If I update via terminal or via updater-manager I will loss all my files? I'm asking because I have a lot of GB and I don't have an external storage, like an external HD or pen-drive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) Yes, you can upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 directly. No, you won't lose any personal files but back them up before you upgrade anyway. Upgrades almost always have rough edges. They are almost never perfect. Once I tried immediately upgrading a fresh install of 13.10 to 14.04, and I got errors even doing that (the upgrade worked though).

Comment: By errors I mean a few error messages and warnings in the terminal while upgrading, which I ignored because everything seemed to be working properly after the upgrade was finished.

Comment: @Cona.684 you could consider storing them online. Google drive for instance. Even if you upgrade 99 times before the 100th time you might make a mistake formatting or there is a bug in the install and your data might be gone. -always- backup before you do. It is better to stick with 13.10 if you do not. Or get a pendrive (waiting a couple of days wont be a problem will it?). Better safe then sorry.

Comment: I'm Uploading my files online already, but it's been a while, since I have too much personal files. I'v already excluded some of them, but it remains too much. In my country an external HD It's expensive for my financials right now. I thing I will have to keep uploading them all. But thanks, for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upgrade will in no way destroy any of your data. 
The worst thing that could happen is that the upgrade fails or breaks booting of the system.

The consequence of that will be that you cannot boot your operating system Yes.
But the DATA will still be safely available on the disk itself.

You simply need to boot of a live CD to retrieve it.

If you are so afraid of loosing data in an upgrade (improbable) you should already have a system backup available since its a higher risk of loosing your DATA through disk failure than an upgrade

Comment: I'll keep uploading my personal files into a cloud storage. But your answer help me, I was almost upgranding. Thanks!